# How to implement M-N relationship to reflect the domain correctly

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented, domain-driven-design, entity-framework

If I have three entities like this:

1. WorkingGroup
2. WorkingTime
3. Shift

The WorkingGroup has one or more workingTime

```
public class WorkingGroup
    {
        public WorkingGroup()
        {
            IsActive = true;
            IsDefault = false;
            WorkingTimes = new List<WorkingTime>();
        }
        private ICollection<WorkingTime> _workingTimes;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short NumberOfSuccessions { get; set; }
        public short WeekStart { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public short NumberOfWeekends { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WorkingTime> WorkingTimes { get => _workingTimes; set => _workingTimes = value; }
    }
```

---

```
public class WorkingTime
    {
        public WorkingTime()
        {
            WorkingTimeActivations = new List<WorkingTimeActivation>();
        }
        private ICollection<WorkingTimeActivation> _workingTimeActivations;
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short NumberOfHours { get; set; }
        public short NumberOfShortDays { get; set; }
        public int WorkingGroupId { get; set; }
        public WorkingGroup WorkingGroup { get; set; }
        public ICollection<WorkingTimeActivation> WorkingTimeActivations { get => _workingTimeActivations; set => _workingTimeActivations = value; }
    }
```

---

```
public class Shift
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ShiftType { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShiftStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShiftEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime DayStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime DayEnd { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan GracePeriodStart { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan GracePeriodEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Now I'm a little confused how to implement the relationship between `WorkingTime & Shift`
It looks like `M-N` relationship.
WorkingTime for **WorkingGroup (A) has 2 records(Summer 8hours,Winter 6hours)**

Now If the user selects `WorkingGroup (A)` to create a `shift` for it:
It should create a shift for the `workingTime(Summer)` for example from `08:00 to 16:00`, and another one for the  `workingTime(Winter)` for example from `08:00 to 14:00`

---

> What's the aggregate root in this case? and How to implement this
>   relationship to reflect it correctly in DB?

Comment: Why not having `Shift.WorkingTimeId`?

Comment: @Fabio because the shift has from-to time for each (workingtime)

Comment: So one shift record will "represent" one working time record?

Comment: @Fabio yeah that's right